# how to align justify in vim editor?

Tags: vim, terminal, formatting, editor, text-alignment

I'd like to use vim to edit long texts (prose / no code), in a well formatted way.

Let consider this file:

[image: lorem_original screenshot]

I can use sentences, paragraphs, etc. vim's features but the long sentences formatting isa bit ugly/poor readable.

So I'd like to have a some justification alignement with strict fixed colums width (let say columns = exactly 100).

I done some tests instlalling `par` unix command line utility (`sudo apt-get install par`) and setting vim to use it (with 'justify' flag):

```
:set formatprg=par\ jw100
```

and doing vim command:

```
gqG
```

but without a perfect joy, see screenshot here:

[image: not-perfect alkignement using par]

as you see I don't have an exact justification to 100 chars. 
why ?! It could be depend because par do not recognize some >8bit chars (of Italian language text here) ?

In fact there is a second issue: I don't want to permanently convert the original text in an aligned elaboration that destroy original sentence (introducing blanks/new line), but i would just VIEW the text leaving the original text untouched. There is a way  to do that formatted view mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Vim has `:set wrap`, and that's it. Remember, it's not a WYSIWYG editor, so viewing as justified text is out of scope.

You would indeed have to convert the physical text (back and forth). If the `par` utility doesn't work (I think it should deal with UTF-8 encoded text; check your `$LANG` value for that), you could also give the `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/justify.vim` script that ships with Vim a try.

Comment: in facts $LANG=en_US.UTF-8 instead the text I reported is Italian. Using a english text par behave correctly.

Comment: I installed Italian locale ($sudo locale-gen it_IT.UTF-8; export LANG='it_IT.UTF-8') and checked inside vim :language confirm vim understand now Italian (Lingua in uso: "LC_CTYPE=it_IT.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=it_IT.utf8;LC_COLLATE=it_IT.utf8;LC_MONETARY=it_IT.utf8;LC_MESSAGES=it_IT.utf8;LC_PAPER=it_IT.
utf8;LC_NAME=it_IT.utf8;LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.utf8;LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.utf8;LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.utf8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.utf8"
), nevertheless the above mentioned formatting still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

To temporarily use `par` on your file, make sure you've saved with `:w` and then use `:!par jw100 <% | less`, it will show you a readonly scrollable 100-char justified version of your file. When you are done, hit q and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here's an example on some Lorem Ipsum text:

[image]

Comment: plus 1 for the screencast :-) but maybe leaving vim to use less is maybe not the best especially with a big file

Comment: Maybe, I just tried it on a 13,052 line file (Sherlock Holmes) and it was nearly instananeous. However, I am pretty sure Emacs has justification built in somewhere, it might be worth checking out.

Comment: thanks Tobi! I'm now trying to understand why par do not justify a text in Italian language (see comments here above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177598/how-to-align-justify-in-vim-editor/28202391?noredirect=1#comment44787166_28188169 )

Answer (score 0):

A regex to achieve this:

```
:%s/\([^,]\{100}\)/\1\r/g
```

Also could place `hyphen` at end-of-line split words with:

```
:%s/\(\w\)$\n\(\w\)/\1-\r\2/g
```

And so on and so forth.